# Tracking .NET Transaction, in SQL

Tags: sql, .net, transactions

I define a transaction like this (VB.NET)

```
Dim objTransaction As New Transaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, "OpenTransaction")
```

do the processes and then close it with

```
 objTransaction.Commit()
 objTransaction.Dispose()
```

or a

```
objTransaction.Rollback()
```

if there is an error.

Now if the transaction is open, how can I find "OpenTransaction" within SQL?

I do a

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
```

and it gives - name = "user_transaction", not "OpenTransaction". How can I find the name I gave it, within SQL?

(I have several users all doing different things on a webpage, I find there is an long running open transaction within SQL, but can't find out what the name is I gave it in code).

Comment: user_transaction is your transaction.Further you can use sys.dm_exec_requests to know sql text

Comment: Thanks, but there could be dozens of "user_transaction".

I can find the SPID, and then "DBCC INPUTBUFFER(XX)" to find the SQL. But I actually want the Transaction Name that I specified in code, as the SQL can be so similar in multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL Profiler for that purpose. you can start it inside SQL management studio like this then set your filters and start Trace

check [this](https://blog.wsol.com/using-sql-server-profiler-to-collect-valuable-performance-metrics) link for more information

**UPDATE**

you can Also use this query to monitor transactions:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_who3]

AS
BEGIN

SET
   TRANSACTION isolation level READ uncommitted;
SELECT
   SPID = er.session_id,
   BlkBy = 
   CASE
      WHEN
         lead_blocker = 1 
      THEN
         - 1 
      ELSE
         er.blocking_session_id 
   END
, ElapsedMS = er.total_elapsed_time , CPU = er.cpu_time , IOReads = er.logical_reads + er.reads , IOWrites = er.writes , Executions = ec.execution_count , CommandType = er.command , LastWaitType = er.last_wait_type , ObjectName = Object_schema_name(qt.objectid, dbid) + '.' + Object_name(qt.objectid, qt.dbid) , SQLStatement = Substring ( qt.text, er.statement_start_offset / 2, 
   CASE
      WHEN
         (
            CASE
               WHEN
                  er.statement_end_offset = - 1 
               THEN
                  Len(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), qt.text)) * 2 
               ELSE
                  er.statement_end_offset 
            END
            - er.statement_start_offset / 2 
         )
         < 0 
      THEN
         0 
      ELSE
         CASE
            WHEN
               er.statement_end_offset = - 1 
            THEN
               Len(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), qt.text)) * 2 
            ELSE
               er.statement_end_offset 
         END
         - er.statement_start_offset / 2 
   END
) , STATUS = ses.status , [Login] = ses.login_name , Host = ses.host_name , DBName = Db_name(er.database_id) , StartTime = er.start_time , Protocol = con.net_transport , transaction_isolation = 
   CASE
      ses.transaction_isolation_level 
      WHEN
         0 
      THEN
         'Unspecified' 
      WHEN
         1 
      THEN
         'Read Uncommitted' 
      WHEN
         2 
      THEN
         'Read Committed' 
      WHEN
         3 
      THEN
         'Repeatable' 
      WHEN
         4 
      THEN
         'Serializable' 
      WHEN
         5 
      THEN
         'Snapshot' 
   END
, ConnectionWrites = con.num_writes , ConnectionReads = con.num_reads , ClientAddress = con.client_net_address , Authentication = con.auth_scheme , DatetimeSnapshot = Getdate() , plan_handle = er.plan_handle 
FROM
   sys.dm_exec_requests er 
   LEFT JOIN
      sys.dm_exec_sessions ses 
      ON ses.session_id = er.session_id 
   LEFT JOIN
      sys.dm_exec_connections con 
      ON con.session_id = ses.session_id OUTER apply sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS qt OUTER apply ( 
      SELECT
         execution_count = Max(cp.usecounts) 
      FROM
         sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
      WHERE
         cp.plan_handle = er.plan_handle ) ec OUTER apply ( 
         SELECT
            lead_blocker = 1 
         FROM
            master.dbo.sysprocesses sp 
         WHERE
            sp.spid IN 
            (
               SELECT
                  blocked 
               FROM
                  master.dbo.sysprocesses WITH (nolock) 
               WHERE
                  blocked != 0
            )
            AND sp.blocked = 0 
            AND sp.spid = er.session_id ) lb 
         WHERE
            er.sql_handle IS NOT NULL 
            AND er.session_id != @@SPID 
         ORDER BY
            CASE
               WHEN
                  lb.lead_blocker = 1 
               THEN
                  - 1 * 1000 
               ELSE
                  - er.blocking_session_id 
            END
, er.blocking_session_id DESC, er.logical_reads + er.reads DESC, er.session_id;
END
```

and create an SP. You can use

> EXEC sp_who3

it will give you all the running transaction that user has you can also edit it in your need.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm needing to do this reactively, not proactively.

Comment: I run the code, putting a breakpoint in after the Transaction is created. The Transaction appears in sys.dm_tran_active_transactions, links to sys.dm_tran_session_transactions. But not in your query (or a similar one I have), and I can't get to the Transaction Name that I give it in code. Thinking I may need to read up on 'Context_Info' to push data into sys.dm_exec_sessions.

Comment: It's odd because i am using this script with .Net and it works fine